# Responsive design sub-menu scrolls back to top

Tags: responsive-design, scroll, submenu

my website : http://trueensan.com/en/

When it is in responsive view, and you hit the menu button it wont show the sub-menu instead it scrolls back to top and the url becomes: http://trueensan.com/en/#

is there anything I can do

Regards ...

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly into your question, because if you change your website, your question will no longer make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my observations on your website, the navigation is set to display: none when in responsive mode

```
#navigation ul {
width: 100%;
display: none;
height: auto;
padding: 0;
}
```

You might need to use some javascript to toggle the display of the nav ul element when the menu icon is clicked. Something like

```
$("nav a#pull").click(function() {
    $( "#navigation ul" ).toggle();
  });
```

I haven't tested this though. I also noticed that there is a custom script not being fetched on the site which might be why the menu is broken in the first place (check the developer console). Try checking if the customscript.js file is missing.

GET http://trueensan.com/wp-content/themes/point-child/js/customscript.js?ver=null 404 (Not Found)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Copying the (customscript.js) to the child theme nailed the solution ... Thank you very much